# Use of so called for...to complementizer with certain adjectives

Tags: grammar, complements, to-infinitive

We can use "for...to" construction with many adjectives.

> I am happy for you to be admitted to college.
>
> I am glad for you to have finally found a job.
>
> I am willing for you to go ahead and try it.
>
> I am honored for my son to receive the award.

So I thought this construction can be used with EVERY adjective that can take to-infinitive as an adjective complement. But it doesn't seem like it.

> *I am sad for you to do it.
>
> *I am afraid for you to try it.

Even though these two adjectives can take to-infinitive as an adjective complement, it sounds strange when I use "for" to introduce a new subject of the infinitive.

Why can some of the adjectives have "for...to" construction and introduce a new subject of the infinitive while the some can't? And is there a category of adjectives that are able or prohibited to have this construction?

Comment: The only one of those I would use is *I am willing for you to go ahead and try it.*. The others I would rephrase, such as: *I am glad you finally got a job* and *I'm happy that you were admitted to college*. This doesn't answer the question, which is why I have written a comment. Note that *willing* talks about a person's will, not a feeling.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Would you say that the four sentences I provided are ungrammatical? I myself don't use it for..to construction very often and lean more towards using that-clause. But I found many people using the construction, so I became curious.

Comment: I dunno. *I'm afraid for you to try it* doesn't sound too bad to me. Is there a webpage or other resource that you were looking at reharding this construction?

Comment: @AlanCarmack https://www.englishforums.com/English/IAfraidDo/bwbpbq/post.htm This guy says it's downright wrong. When I hear "afraid for you to", it sounds very strange to me.

Comment: As far as basic grammar (spelling and parts of speech) is concerned, they are OK. But the last two don't make any sense in context. For example, when you match emotions (sad/afraid) with actions (do/try) it does not make sense. If you believe they do, add detailed context as to what is happening around the statement.

Comment: @user3169 I know the last two are wrong.

Comment: @user3169 I think it is very strange though. Some adjectives work well with   for..to, but some of them doesn't. I think it is closelyy related to the property of the adjectives, which I cannot figure out.

Answer (score 1):

If one finds

> I am happy for you to go to college

felicitous, then I can see no reason for that same person to judge

> I am sad for you to go to college

infelicitous. People may not say it, but this does not mean it is an invalid structure.

I also disagre with whoever said

> I am afraid for you to try it

is not felicitous, because quick internet searches show that

*to be afraid for someone to-do something* to be in use. See, for example, searches for

[afraid for you to](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22afraid+for+you+to%22&oq=%22afraid+for+you+to%22&gs_l=serp.3...4733.6417.0.6917.6.6.0.0.0.0.132.714.0j6.6.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.2.234...30i10.Eh61qRxYTKI)
[afraid for him to](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22afraid+for+him+to%22&oq=%22afraid+for+him+to%22&gs_l=serp.3...42905.44241.0.45020.6.6.0.0.0.0.148.635.0j5.5.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.2.280...30i10.hOIcjrb4t5E)
[afraid for her to](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22afraid+for+her+to%22&oq=%22afraid+for+her+to%22&gs_l=serp.3...17215.17592.0.17946.4.4.0.0.0.0.128.441.1j3.4.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.1.127...30i10.mwaioVv4kQA), etc.

This is the same structure as

> I am anxious for you to go to college

which is felicitous.

As for the **for...to** construction, it is debatable whether *for* here is a complementizer (see *[Modality and Subordinators](https://books.google.com/books?id=86v3bjkjYskC&pg=PA262&dq=%22for-to+construction+is+a+complementizer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixj_S7hfLNAhUBeCYKHfzqC98Q6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22for-to%20construction%20is%20a%20complementizer%22&f=false)*).

Also, while there are many *for...to* constructions judged to be felicitous, there are many that I would not say.

For example:

> I *want* for you to do that.

sounds incredibly stilted and/or the product of a linguist in an ivory tower,  whereas

> I *want* you to do that.

(omitting *for*) sounds natural.

I would never say

> ??He spoke louder for me to hear

even though the following parallel construction is fine:

> He moved over for me to get past.

As for as the adjectives you ask about, I suppose many are in the ear of the speaker... As I said, I have no problem with

> I am willing for you to go ahead and try it.

but I don't like

> ? I am honored for my son to receive the award.

I would rather use

> I am honored for my son to have received the award.

In general, the *for-to* construction seems hit or miss for me, even when judged felicitous by others, including linguists.